How to read cyrillic in PHP url?
I'm trying to create Wordpress WooCommerce plugin where I can scrape url product from partner shop and get the product title, description, images automatically in my website. My problem is that url contains mix of latin and cyrillic letters. Here's everything go wrong. Instead of the url: garvan.bg/collections/шлемови-каски/products/шлемова-каска-размер-л-4
I got
https://www.garvan.bg/collections/-/products/----4
therefore I get 404 the page does not exist. How to fix url?
    function link_scraper_debugger_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Link Scraper Debugger</h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <label for="scrape_url">Enter URL to Scrape:</label>
        <input type="text" id="scrape_url" name="scrape_url" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">
        <input type="submit" name="scrape_submit" value="Scrape" class="button button-primary">
    </form>
</div>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['scrape_submit'])) {
    $url = sanitize_text_field($_POST['scrape_url']);
    if (!empty($url)) {
        link_scraper_debugger_process($url);
    }
}


function link_scraper_debugger_process($url) {
$decoded_url = urldecode($url);

$args = array(
    'redirection' => 5, 
    'headers' => array(
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
    )
);

$response = wp_remote_get($decoded_url, $args);
if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    echo '<div class="notice notice-error is-dismissible"><p>Failed to fetch URL: ' . $response->get_error_message() . '</p></div>';
    return;
}

full code here
https://pastebin.com/E7SKUihE

Why are you applying sanitize_text_field to this value?

You're right. I added it to check for valid UTF-8 but is in cyrillic. Thank you
